# How do I measure the noise at the top of a square wave?

Tags: analog, voltage-measurement

I am trying to get a good measurement of the "quality" of a square wave, both in its flatness and lack of noise at both high and low levels.

Low level is easy, just use a preamp and zoom way in with a scope.

But how do I do this at the high level?  The scope doesn't have enough offset for me to just zoom into the top of the waveform, and the preamp won't work there either, since with all that gain it's way out of range.  Is there a clever trick to be able to do this?

(AC coupling doesn't help, it's still way out of range)

Answer (score 1):

If it is a square wave, one can measure "quality"
by multiplying it by a clean synchronous reference (square wave) and filtering (or not) the result.

Comment: Nice idea. Is there any convenient way to clean up this square wave to create a synchronous copy?  And how do I multiply without more noise being added?  I'm working in the 50uVpp range of noise (target).

Comment: And ... what frequency?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create a clean offset voltage. It will probably saturate your scope amplifier when it goes low but that's the same problem as happens on the low side.

Most scopes have a common that is tied to earth ground so it might be a bit tricky if you don't have something like the Tek TPS2024 with floating inputs.

Or (depending on signal frequency etc.) maybe use a data acquisition system with more resolution than an oscilloscope.

Comment: I actually do have a TPS2024 around!  I'll try that. Yes, saturating is no big deal, I just have to measure peaks and valleys separately.

Comment: I don't recall the exact specs, but 50uV might be asking a bit much of the scope though, even x1 and BW limited.